# ASP.NET MVC jqgrid pass row to controller by row save button

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have a Jqgrid with an editable column and showing Actions column. If i click on edit button, on the row, I can change the value of first column ( cause it is editable ). Then Jqgrid shows two buttons like "save" and "reset". How I can pass the row value to a controller when click on save icon? How generally I catch these buttons and call/send data to a controller?

this is the jqgrid script:

```
$("#grid").jqGrid({
        data: tabledata,
        datatype: 'local',
        edit:true,

        colNames: ['Actions','Name', 'Surname'],
        colModel: [
                        { name: 'Actions', width: 50, align: 'left', search: false, formatter: 'actions',
                          formatoptions: { keys: true,editbutton:true}
                        },
                        { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', , editable: true},
                        { name: 'Surname', index: 'LoopYears' }
          ],

        pager: $('#gridpager'),
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        sortname: 'id',
        sortorder: "desc",
        viewrecords: true,
        imgpath: 'themes/basic/images',
        caption: 'My first grid',
        cellEdit: true
    });
```

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used - Guriddo jqGrid, free-jqGrid or jqGrid <= version 4.7?. If you use Guriddo jqGrid you may want to read the [docs here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/editing/#inline-posted-data), where we describe what is posted to the server. Additionally you maybe need to use serilaizeRowData to stringify this result to your ASP.NET MVC controller. [More here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/editing/#inline-editing)

Comment: it's jqGrid 3.8.2

Comment: jqGrid 3.8.2 is about 7 years old. The goal of stackoverflow - sharing of *common* questions and solutions, which could have some value *for other people*. jqGrid 3.8.2 is too old to be used now. You should upgrade it to one from two currently developing successor of jqGrid: [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.15.1, which I develop, or commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334), which develop Tony Tomov.